# iOS app crashes after pressing info button on scanning screen with cn1-codescan lib

Tags: codenameone

Issue related to https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan

I create a bear bone application and added cn1-codescan lib to scan QR code.

In iOS version of the build, there is a Cancel and Info button at the bottom of the screen and when you press the info button, the application just crash/close immediately with no errors.

[Here is an iOS app screenshot with info button causing the app crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7K71.jpg)

Not reproducible in Android as there is simply no such buttons

The mentioned code is nothing else but a tutorial example

```
    CodeScanner.getInstance().scanQRCode(new ScanResult() {

    public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
        //barCode.setText("Bar: " + contents);
        cnt.addComponent(new Label(contents));
        cnt.revalidate();
    }

    public void scanCanceled() {
        System.out.println("cancelled");
    }

    public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
        System.out.println("err " + message);
    }
});
```

I think it is something wrong with iOS native code and in particular with ZBar implementation of QR code scanning library but not sure what exactly. Could someone help please?

Comment: That might be a side effect of moving from UIWebView to WKWebView. Thanks for the headsup can you please file an issue here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new and we'll address it

Comment: Thank you, Shai. I submitted issue here as you proposed https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3287